# Not able to view the renamed query design in MS Access query design

Tags: ms-access

I have created one query on the basis of other query in the MS access 2007.my newly created query name is 'qryExcessinIMS'.But later I changed the name of this query as 'qryIMSandTemplate'.the name got changed in view query .But still not changed in create query design Show Table as shown in the image.Please help me how to change in both memmory;[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Have you checked the box for Perform name AutoCorrect (all under Office button | Access options | Current database)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete the query from Custom Group or switch the view from Custom type to, for instance, Object Type, then rename. If you rename the query in custom group, it renames only alias, base query remains with the same name.